# Android Studio Git merging shows empty screens and the conflict could not be resolved

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, built on July 26, 2021, on macOS 10.15.7.

When I tried to merge two branches in the last conflict I got empty screens:

[image]

I tried to accept incoming changes but the conflict stays. I am pretty sure that the files are not empty ;). I tried to delete the files but had no success I noticed that some strange file is created in the conflicted file folder and maybe it makes the problem with this weird extension. Does anyone have an easy solution to this?

[image]

Comment: Do you want an android-studio based answer, or a Git-command-line based answer? If the former, keep the android-studio tag and drop the [tag:git] tag. If the latter (or both), keep the git tag.

Comment: I think it is some kind of bug in Android studio git plugin

Comment: It could be, yes. But that would mean it's not a Git issue. Plugins for Android Studio are not Git, even if they use Git, any more than plugins that use a shell are shells.